# Spring AMQP: Inspecting RabbitMQ config

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to demo the usage of RabbitMQ Credit Flow mechanism as per the blog mentioned here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/10/06/new-credit-flow-settings-on-rabbitmq-3-5-5/

As part of my demo, I want to show that the RabbitMQ will block the publisher from further publishing the messages if the consumer is not able to process the messages.

On the consumer side, I am persisting the message in the database. I have put the RabbitMQ acknowledge mode to MANUAL. The code on the consumer side EXPLICITLY acknowledges after the message is successfully persisted in the database.

As part of my demo, I have set the credit_flow_default_credit parameter in the rabbitmq.config file to 2.

Accordingly, my rabbitmq.config file look as below:

```
[
   {rabbit,[
        {loopback_users, []},
        {credit_flow_default_credit, {2,1}} 
     ]
   }     
].
```

As per my understanding, if RabbitMQ is not able to handle 2 messages then the 3rd message published by the publisher must be blocked.

To achieve what I want, I LOCK the table in the database so that the consumer is not able to persist the record. As a result, it will also not be able to ACKNOWLEDGE.

However, I don't see that the publisher has any problem in publishing the message even though it has already published 2 messages. Why shouldn't the RabbitMQ block further publishing of the messages?

Is there a way I can inspect the rabbitmq.config from the Spring AMQP? I want to make sure that the credit_flow_default_credit is indeed set to 2.

Answer (score 1):

No; it's a broker property; the java client can only do things suported by the AMQP protocol.

I suggest you ask questions about RabbitMQ internals (such as why you are not seeing the behavior you expect) on the rabbitmq-users Google group, where the RabbitMQ engineers are active.

They do look here from time-to-time, but you will likely get a faster response here.

However, you should continue to ask here about things specific to Spring AMQP.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I have put the same question on RabbitMQ Google group.